# Change tableview multiple selection javafx

Tags: javafx, colors, tableview, row

I want to change the color of `TableView` row in  multiple selection mode. I 've used `setStyle("-fx-selection-bar: red;")` to set color in single selection mode.

I tried `setStyle("-fx-selection-bar-non-focused: salmon;")` but this code change the color of the selections when table is unfocused.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `-fx-control-inner-background`?

```xml
.table-row-cell {
    -fx-control-inner-background: orange;
    -fx-selection-bar: red;
}
```

[image]